# Efficient and Transaction-safe Ways to Process Millions of Rows with Multiple Table Joins in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, transactions

This does not necessarily apply only to the Laravel php framework as I believe my intended tasks can be processed on the MySQL server itself as well with appropriate SQL statements.

There are 3 tables as following:

> users (>2 million rows)
>
> - id
> - name
> - balance (decimal, 14, 2)
> - package_id
>
> packages (5 rows)
>
> - id
> - name
> - value (decimal, 14, 2)
> - percent (decimal, 5, 2) *- stored as 0.10 instead of 10*
>
> transactions (log)
>
> - id
> - user_id
> - description
> - amount

All of the tables above are linked to the objects/models User, Package, and Transaction respectively. They contain timestamp columns and are inserted/updated automatically by Laravel.

1. The application is scheduled to update the column **balance** in table **users** based on the **value** of package (that is assigned to the user) multiplied by **percent** field plus the original balance value, every day at midnight 12:00am. A clearer expression would be:

   > users.balance = users.balance + (packages.value * packages.percent)
2. At the same time, a transaction log for each balance update should be inserted to the database:

   > user_id: [user's id] 
   >   description: Updated user [user's name] with new balance
   >   amount: [amount added]

I have managed to achieve the first operation with the following SQL statements:

```
UPDATE users 
INNER JOIN packages 
ON users.package_id = packages.id
SET users.balance = users.balance + (packages.value * packages.percent);
```

I can't seem to find any solution to achieve both operations at the same time with highest efficiency and transaction-safe. I could possibly retrieve both users and packages and process them in the application then do UPDATEs and INSERTs, but it'd be a no-brainer thing to do as it's really inefficient.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me with the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any possible way to update or insert on two different tables in mysql. I know of updating 2 different tables with one query but not insert and update on 2 different tables. I think you can use **triggers** to achieve what you want

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_into_logs_when_user_balance_update
AFTER UPDATE ON users 
FOR EACH ROW
  IF NEW.balance <> OLD.balance
  then
    insert into logs(user_id, description, amount)
    values(New.id, New.balance, New.balance)
  END IF
```

This will update logs tables when users.balance changes/update.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works perfectly! One more question, when I tried out the method above, it seems that only 2-3 cores out of 24 were being utilized, and it took 24 seconds to process 1 million users (server has 90GB RAM with SSD). I have tried increasing innodb R/W threads to 48, and the speed is still nearly the same. Any idea on how to reduce the execution time?

Comment: You can set innodb_thread_concurrency to 0 for infinite concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Luke You want to update user record and concurrently insert log record both with same query. You should check Mysql duplicate key update.
I suggest to check this link. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
http://www.digimantra.com/tutorials/insert-update-single-mysql-query-duplicate-key/